# Using thread.sleep in controller

Tags: java, spring

I need to delay my method to give a time for animation (1500ms) in my frontend.
After animation I want to return refreshed list of objects.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete_client/{clientId}")
public String deleteClient(@PathVariable String clientId, 
    @ModelAttribute("deleteClient") Client client) {
       client.setId(clientId);
       clientRepository.delete(client);
       try {
          Thread.sleep(1600);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return "redirect:/clients";

}
```

I am curious if its a good way to delay this method.

Comment: That's a terrible idea. Why don't you handle that on the front-end?

Comment: Absolutely, use a callback method in your front side that its triggered after the animation

Comment: ...i saw this (thread sleep in requestmapping) in some good rep. tutorial (baeldung or similar ..maybe even in spring-samples), but of course only for demonstration and test use, but since... It's maybe not best idea...but could work (as intended). ...but the "intent" is not best in your scenario! (-> client side!)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that's absolutely awful idea to delay controller. Make it in your JS! And only there!